# Enable one finger swipe in Google Chrome on OS X Lion & Magic Mouse

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, osx-lion, gestures

Is there a way to use the one finger swipe gesture with the Apple Magic Mouse in Google Chrome as the back button, just like in Apple Safari 5.1? I know one can set OS X back to use the two finger swipe,and in this case it the gesture works fine in Chrome (and any other browser), but I would like to use the one two finger swipe in Chrome. I'm using the Chrome canary build.

Comment: Voting to close as questions about Chrome Canary sound too localized in time to be of any lasting value.

Comment: try out Better Touch Tool http://blog.boastr.net/

Comment: @Daniel: I only mentioned Canary because I'm using it ATM, the answer may well be universal and work for all Chrome builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Google Chrome Canary build (15.0.855.0) supports the one finger swipe gesture. This feature will probably be pushed down to the other Google Chrome builds other time.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I've found that fixes this issue is to [disable the **Use hardware acceleration when available**](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/laHTHoWvviw/oqxgWko0CQAJ) setting in `Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)` which is obviously NOT ideal.

EDIT: This has become broken again in Chrome since this question was posted and another answer mentioned it is fixed in Canary.

EDIT(2): This appears to be fixed once again in `Version 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit)` even after re-enabling the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option under advanced settings. I wonder if just toggling this setting off, relaunching the browser and then re-enabling the setting fixes this problem.

Comment: disabling hw acceleration also fixed this issue for me for Catalina (10.15.7), thanks, but strange thing: it seems google chrome still fails with it for many years already (

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This answer only applies for the trackpad, and does not work for the Magic Mouse.

The answer is yes. I'm not convinced this is too localised, as this set up is very tied in to OS X Lion, so it's likely that this will trickle down into the main build and remain true. Additionally, as of the date of writing this, the same method works in the Google Chrome Beta channel.

Anyway, open **System Preferences**, then open the **Trackpad** panel. Open the **More Gestures** tab, and then change the *Swipe Between Pages* dropdown setting to read *Scroll left or right with **two** fingers*.

The screen should then look like this (with the relevant option highlighted):
[image]

Comment: @Lujasa: This works fine with a trackpad, but this option is not available when using the Apple magic mouse. Maybe I should change the answer to `Use one finger swipe gesture with Google Chrome and Apple magic mouse`

Comment: Ah, ok. To the best of my knowledge, the Magic Mouse has a much more limited set of gestures in Lion than does the trackpad. I am pretty sure that the gesture for Chrome is derived from the *Swipe between pages* setting, so if it doesn't exist for the Magic Mouse then it looks like you can't enable it, at least not now.

Comment: The option IS available with the magic mouse, and one can also set it to `swipe with one finger`, which is also the default setting in 10.7, but it dose not work in Chrome and any other browser besides Safari. If one sets it to two finger swipe, it works without a problem.

Comment: Odd. Can you try it in the Chrome Beta build? http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/

Comment: Don't think it'll make a difference, but I'll try. The one finger swipe solely works in Safari.

Comment: Nope, no dice. Didn't work.

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. I'm upvoting the question based on that oddity.